# Can I selectively refactor files from a non-ARC project to be ARC compliant?

Tags: xcode4, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5

**Scenario:**

I have inherited a non-ARC project that I wish to refactor.

**Problem:**

There's a few CF-dependent files (some 3-party) that are screwing up the refactoring.

How can I use the automated ARC refactoring whilst avoiding these troublesome files?

... or do I merely selectively set -fno-objc-arc/-fobjc-arc flags around them in the build phase instead of via the 'front-door' refactoring option?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "screwing up"?

Comment: 'Screwing up' - adding wrong remedies to ARC complaints causing fatal run crash.  I would rather add ARC piecemeal to the project vs screwing up.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the Convert to ARC tool in Xcode, you should be presented with a preview of the changes. On the left of that panel is a list of the files that will be changed. Unchecking the files that you want to leave untouched should make the refactoring tool skip over them:

[image]

Then add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag to these files in the Build Phases Pane

[image]

and you should be all set.

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  Is there a way to view the arc/noarc compiler flags in the build phase or build settings of an existing project?    I don't see any such flags once I create a new project as either ARC or non-ARC.

Comment: Yes; select the project itself in the file list and you will get views of the various build settings for both the project and its targets.